# iTunes Match: one song will not download or play from iCloud, another skips

Tags: itunes, icloud

I'm using iTunes Match with iCloud to store my music catalog. Mostly, I'm super happy with the service and the amount of work Apple have done to make it work so well.

However, I have a couple of specific issues, and I'm wondering if there is a solution anyone has found, or whether I should just submit these issues to Apple and cross my fingers.

**Issue 1:**

I uploaded an album to iCloud. There is one song on the album that will neither play from iCloud or download to any device. If I try to play the song, it is skipped and the next one starts to play. Is there something I can try or is this something for Apple to investigate?

**Issue 2:**

I purchased a song from iTunes a number of years ago. It is part of a compilation that is pretty hard to find anywhere else (it's from 1998). The track in question suffers from bad encoding and skips at a certain point. Even if I found another copy of the track somewhere else, the one in iCloud would still be Apple's encoded version. Has anyone ever had any luck in getting Apple to fix an issue like this? I contacted them and they never responded.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be about using a web application.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be about using a web application.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and what I did was that:

- I deleted that song from iTunes (it will ask you if you want to move
  it to trash. Say yes and delete it it from your trash can)
- beside the song, the iCloud symbol should pop back up, click it and it
  should work fine.

Comment: Nope. This is a badly encoded track on Apple's side. The track has been downloaded on an iPod, an iPhone, and two different MacBook Pros. It even skips when played on Apple TV. This isn't something that happened because of a weird download.